# Why does EXISTS return tuples with some nulls included

Tags: ssas, mdx

I must be misinterpreting the function `EXISTS`.
Why does the following return lots of customers with `null` revenues?
What function should I be using or am I right to use `EXISTS` but need to use it differently?

```
WITH SET [CustomerSet] AS
    EXISTS( 
    [Customer].[Customer].MEMBERS,
        (
        [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Month].&[201312],
        [Measures].[Revenues])
        )
select 
   [CustomerSet] on columns
from [ourCube]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - `EXISTS` basically mimics `auto-exists` behaviour without having to include two levels of a cross-join in the resulting cellset. If the two arguments are not from the same dimension then auto-exist behaviour does not occur - this is the reason for the failure of my original script. There is an optional third argument, which is very useful in this situation, and creates a context using a chosen measure group for auto-exist behaviour:

```
WITH SET [CustomerSet] AS
    EXISTS( 
    [Customer].[Customer].MEMBERS,
    [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Month].&[201312],
    "Revenues Measure Group"
    )
SELECT 
   [CustomerSet] ON COLUMNS
FROM [ourCube]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrap Date, Revenues in NONEMPTY

```
NONEMPTY (
        [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Month].&[201312],
        [Measures].[Revenues])
        )
```

Comment: once back near the cubes I'll give this a go - although still doubtful. Just read an article that explained that `EXISTS` works well if the two sets are from the same dimension as it uses the Auto-Exist feature similar to cross-joining two different levels from same dimension.

Comment: Also I suspect I should try using the third argument of the `EXISTS` function i.e. get rid of `[Measures].[Revenues]` from the query and specify its measure group as the third argument.